# Chaining requests in axios so I can do a second request for each element of first request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, httprequest

I need to get a list of friends from one endpoint and then get a number from a different endpoint for every friend I get from the first one. I found how to chain axios requests but only doing single requests one after another and I would like to do it in a loop, perfectly just adding it to every object in the list I get from first request. What I found and could be useful for that was using await so I have this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const friendslist = await Promise.all(axios.get(`users/${global.userID}/friends`));
    console.log(friendslist.data);
    function myFun(item){
        const data = await axios.get(`users/${global.userID}/sum/${item.id}`);
        return data.sum;
    }
    friendslist.forEach(item.sum = myFun);
    this.setState({loading: false, friends: friendslist.data})
};
```

but i don't even get my first request back, console just shows undefined. Sorry if the question was here already but I have not found anything similar or if my explanation is bad - it's my first question here. If it helps backend is in Django but I don't think it changes anything.

Comment: `Promise.all` takes an array of promises, so your first call should fail.

Comment: Oh, that's true, that's my mistake - I corrected it and first call succeeds and I get what I want from it - but still my ``foreach`` doesn't work - I get ``Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: item``. Perhaps it's just my lack of knowledge in js but I don't know how to make it work

Comment: `friendsList.data.forEach`? Also you need an argument in forEach, ie `forEach(item => ...`

Comment: That did it! Well, almost. forEach works fine but I get undefined from the call in it. My code looks like that  now:

`async componentDidMount() {
        const friendslist = await axios.get(`users/${global.userID}/friends`);
        function myFun(item){
            const resp = axios.get(`users/${global.userID}/sum/${item.id}`);
            console.log(resp.data);
        }
        friendslist.data.forEach(myFun);
        this.setState({loading: false, friends: friendslist.data})
    };`